# Rectangular to polar conversion

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am trying to write this fraction in polar form (4+10i)/(24i-5) . I am having trouble to get the angle of the polar conversion. I know that in order to get the angle I need to write arctan(10/4)-arctan(-24/5) which gives me 146.43 degrees. But the correct answer is 33.57 degrees when I do it by looking at the polar plane.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the correct answer is $+33.57$ degrees? According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(4%2B10i)%2F(24i-5)), the answer is in the fourth quadrant, so the answer should be $-33.57$ degrees.

Comment: @McFry Tangent is always opposite over adjacent, vertical over horizontal, imaginary part over real part. Maryann calculated the first angle's tangent correctly, but they messed up the second angle's tangent because he forgot to account for different quadrants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $-\frac{24}{5}$ is negative, $\tan^{-1} -\frac{24}{5}$ gives you the angle between $-90^\circ$ and $0$ in the fourth quadrant where the imaginary part is negative and the real part is positive. However, the number is $24i-5$, so we want the angle to be where the imaginary part is positive and the real part is negative, so add $180^\circ$ to get $\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{24}{5}\right)+180^\circ$. This brings us into the second quadrant, which is where we want to be.

Now, subtract the first angle from the second angle to get the correct answer:

$$\tan^{-1} \frac{10}{4}-\left(\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{24}{5}\right)+180^\circ\right) \approx -33.57^\circ$$

Comment: So I could not solve it just by subtracting the arctan, I always have to look at the plane?

Comment: Yes, once you calculate the $\tan^{-1}$, you should look at the polar/complex plane and make sure you are in the right quadrant. If you are not in the right quadrant, add $180^\circ$ or $\pi \ \text{rad}$ in order to fix the problem.